# Why is ProtoBuf so slow on the 1st call but very fast inside loops?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Inspired from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715476/protobuf-serialization-missing-data-even-for-simple-entities). I created a small benchmark program to compare ProtoBuf, BinaryFormatter and Json.NET. The benchmark itself is a small console based one at https://github.com/sidshetye/SerializersCompare .Feel free to add/improve, it's quite simple to add a new serializer to the mix. Anyway, my results are:

```
        Binary Formatter         ProtoBuf          Json.NET     ServiceStackJson   ServiceStackJSV
 Loop     Size:512 bytes    Size:99 bytes    Size:205 bytes      Size:205 bytes     Size:181 bytes
    1         16.1242 ms      151.6354 ms       277.2085 ms         129.8321 ms        146.3547 ms
    2          0.0673 ms        0.0349 ms         0.0727 ms           0.0343 ms          0.0370 ms
    4          0.0292 ms        0.0085 ms         0.0303 ms           0.0145 ms          0.0148 ms
    8          0.0255 ms        0.0069 ms         0.0017 ms           0.0216 ms          0.0129 ms
   16          0.0011 ms        0.0064 ms         0.0282 ms           0.0114 ms          0.0120 ms
   32          0.0164 ms        0.0061 ms         0.0334 ms           0.0112 ms          0.0120 ms
   64          0.0347 ms        0.0073 ms         0.0296 ms           0.0121 ms          0.0013 ms
  128          0.0312 ms        0.0058 ms         0.0266 ms           0.0062 ms          0.0117 ms
  256          0.0256 ms        0.0097 ms         0.0448 ms           0.0087 ms          0.0116 ms
  512          0.0261 ms        0.0058 ms         0.0307 ms           0.0127 ms          0.0116 ms
 1024          0.0258 ms        0.0057 ms         0.0309 ms           0.0113 ms          0.0122 ms
 2048          0.0257 ms        0.0059 ms         0.0297 ms           0.0125 ms          0.0121 ms
 4096          0.0247 ms        0.0060 ms         0.0290 ms           0.0119 ms          0.0120 ms
 8192          0.0247 ms        0.0060 ms         0.0286 ms           0.0115 ms          0.0121 ms
```

*Disclaimer*:

1. The results above are from within a Windows VM - the Stopwatch/timer values for very small intervals may not be 100% accurate compared to bare-metal OSes. So ignore ultra low values in the above table.
2. For ServiceStack, the Json and JSV scored were taken from two separate runs. Since they share the same underlying ServiceStack library, running one right after the other affects the "cold start" 1 loop scores for the next run (it's 'warm start' fast)

BinaryFormatter is the largest in size but also the fastest for a single serialization => deserialization loop. However, once we tight loop around the serialization => deserialization code, ProtoBuf is *super* fast.

**Question#1**: Why is ProtoBuf that much slower for a single serialization => deserialization loop?

**Question#2**: From a practical perspective, what can we do to get past that "cold start"? Run at least one object (of any type) through it? Run every (critical) object type through it?

Comment: Maybe you could try pre-compiling your program. For that, you will need to add a strong name to the binary and run ngen.

Comment: @jpa "pre-compiling" and "add a strong name" are two largely unrelated subjects...

Comment: @MarcGravell, IIRC if one uses ngen to pre-compile a .NET binary to the global assembly cache, it only works with a strong name. But of course there are other ways to achieve the same.

Comment: @jpa ah, right; ngen. That won't help here, since JIT compilation  isn't the problem. The issue is that the library does meta-programming - i.e. it writes IL *at runtime* to handle the data it receives (which it doesn't know about ahead of time)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Question#1: Why is ProtoBuf that much slower for a single serialization => deserialization loop?

Because it does a metric ton of work to analyse the model and prepare the strategy; I've spent a lot of time making the generated strategy be as insanely fast as possible, but it could be that I've skimped on optimizations in the meta-programming layer. I'm happy to add that as an item to look at, to reduce the time on a first pass. Of course, on the other hand the meta-programming layer is still twice as fast as Json.NET's equivalent pre-processing ;p

> Question#2: From a practical perspective, what can we do to get past that "cold start"? Run at least one object (of any time) through it? Run every (critical) object type through it?

Various options:

1. use the "precompile" tool as part of your build process, to generate the compiled serializer as a separate fully-static compiled dll that you can reference and use like normal: exactly zero meta-programming then happens
2. explicitly tell the model about the "root" types at startup, and store the output of `Compile()`

   ```
   static TypeModel serializer;
   ...
   RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Foo), true);
   RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Bar), true);
   serializer = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Compile();
   ```

   (the `Compile()` method will analyse from the root-types, adding in any additional types needed as it goes, returning a compiled generated instance)
3. explicitly tell the model about the "root" types at startup, and call `CompileInPlace()` "a few times"; `CompileInPlace()` will not full expand the model - but calling it a few times should cover most bases, since compiling one layer will bring other types into the model

   ```
   RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Foo), true);
   RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Bar), true);
   for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
       RuntimeTypeModel.Default.CompileInPlace();
   }
   ```

Separately, I should probably:

1. add a method to fully expand a model for the `CompileInPlace` scenario
2. spend some time optimizing the meta-programming layer

Final thought: the main difference between `Compile` and `CompileInPlace` here will be what happens if you've forgotten to add some types; `CompileInPlace` works against the existing model, so you can still add new types (implicitly or explicitly) later, and it will "just work"; `Compile` is more rigid: once you've generated a type via that, it is fixed and can handle **only** the types it could deduce at the time it was compiled.

Comment: Awesome, I think the CompileInPlace() is best for most applications. I take it's an in-memory compile, so assuming no one pulls the plug on the hosting application process, what's the lifetime of the compile results?

Comment: @Sid yes, that is entirely in-memory; CompileInPlace works using DynamicMethod, separately per type (each type's method compiled lazily as needed)

Comment: Great, thanks! Where can I readup or ask about thread safety of ProtoBuf? 'Static' and 'in-memory' raise some red flags. I could ask here but can reroute if you have a better venue in mind...

Comment: @Sid actually, the only thing that is `static` is `RuntimeTypeModel.Default`; the core moved from `static` to instance in v2, with `RuntimeTypeModel.Default` providing the implementation for the pre-existing `Serializer.*` methods. But: any `TypeModel` (which is basically the serializer instance) is fully thread-safe. That includes all the methods that are exposed as `Serializer.*` (which proxy to `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.*`)